# internet explorer image specifications

Tags: php, css, image, wordpress, internet-explorer

i am using wordpress and making a statis page there. i needed the background to be an image for part of the content, so i made a new template php file with the code:

```
 <div style="background: url(/xxx.xxx) no-repeat; 
             background-size: 100% auto; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
                 (src='/xxx.xxx',sizingMethod='scale');
             -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
        (src='/xxx.xxx',sizingMethod='scale');">
```

it works well in all other browsers as in the picture width spans everything and the height is proportional, but in internet explorer (version 8) the image is distorted so that the height also spans everything, which i do not want!!

how can i make it so that the image is not distorted and only the width spans everything while the height is still in porportion?

Comment: Microsoft does not support IE 8 any more. If thats your only problem I would leave it. Most people are on 9 or 10

Comment: Make sure you don't use this code on a element that contains input elements. In IE8 user will be unable to access them.

Comment: wait.... so the picture should not be distorted if i went on ie 9 or 10?

Comment: @user3219859 I dont know, you reported the problem for IE8 we assumed you had done other testing and this was the only one giving you trouble. try your code in 9 and 10 I would never support farther back than microsoft does.

Comment: the thing is, i need this to work in ie8 for the office, and it is not within an input field... i just want the height to be auto instead of 100%

Comment: Have you tried doing it in CSS?

Comment: i have done it with a <div style=""> simply beacause this is the code inside a text widget in one of my static pages for my wordpress site

Comment: @SaggingRufus: what are you talking about? Of course MS still supports IE8. They're only going to finally drop IE6 support in April 2014. IE8 will be supported for several years yet.

Comment: Your basic problem here is that IE8 does not support the CSS `background-size` property. There are various solutions/work-arounds to this (of which the `filter` option you've tried is one, but tends to be quite brittle). In most cases the best option in my opinion is to use the [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) polyfill script, which adds support for `background-size` as part of it's `-pie-background` feature. You may also want to [read my blog post](http://spudley.com/blog/css-background-size-and-browser-support) on this topic, which goes into a bit more detail about some of the options.